# Symfony3 Render multiple time same form

Tags: forms, twig, symfony

I would like to **render the same form multiple times** to handle the same action for two different tabs.
The problem is that when I try, only the form of the first tab is shown, event if I change the *id* and ***name*** of the form.
*I found out it's the expected behavior of symfony*, but I still need it to work.

I found that it may works with a collection but don't get how it would work.

twig:

```
{{ form(contactForm, {'attr': {'id': 'contactFormId' ~ Client.Id}, 'name': "contactFormName" ~ Client.Id})}}
```

Form:

```
$this->contactForm = $this->createFormBuilder($contact, array('allow_extra_fields' =>true))
->add('Nom',        TextType::class, array('mapped'=>false))
->add('Prenom',     TextType::class, array('mapped'=>false))
->add('Telephone',  TextType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Téléphone'))
->add('Email',      TextType::class)
->add('Ajouter',    SubmitType::class)
->getForm();
```

Answer (score 9):

It is an older question, but I just came across it facing a similar situation. I wanted to have multiple versions of one form object in a list view. For me the solution was to move the `createView()` call on the form object to the view instead of calling it in the controller. This is kind of a dirty solution regarding separation of concerns, but I thought to post it so it may help others anyway.

My controller action looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("", name="cart_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(Request $request)
{

    /** @var CartInterface $cart */
    $cart = $this->get('rodacker.cart');

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm();

    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:Cart:show.html.twig',
        ['cart' => $cart, 'deleteForm' => $deleteForm]
    );

    // ...
    private function createDeleteForm()
    {
        return $this->createForm(
            OrderItemDeleteType::class,
            null,
            [
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('cart_remove_item'),
                'method' => 'DELETE',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

and in the view I set the `form` variable by calling the `createView` function on the form variable (`deleteForm`) passed from the controller:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% set form =  deleteForm.createView %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.item, {'value': item.image.filename}) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Artikel entfernen">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> entfernen
    </button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actualy I really like the idea. As an object, it's logic to be able to CRUD it so why not also with an interface? Their may be some particular cases where it would not work but I'll give it a try some day.

Comment: In general this works but the issue I am facing is that ids are used multiple times. This leads to problems with some field types.

Answer (score 1):

Once you render a Symfony form, the same form will not render again.

I would suggest creating a form class and calling Controller::createForm() multiple times to create the desired amount of Form instances; you can call isSubmitted etc. on all forms independently.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: The problem is that I will create an unfixed number of form, and it might be numerous. Therefore I can't create that much forms; which would slow a lot the page.

Comment: If you need a variable amount of 'forms' it sounds like the CollectionType field is exactly what you're looking for. You can add entire collections of form fields by supplying your own AbstractType class and dynamically add and remove such entries. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: I've looked to your idea, the problem is that the collection allow to get multiple forms at the same place. I need to render the form at different places with each time a small difference, but an important one. Therefore I don't think I can you the CollectionType::class...

Comment: Javascript can do that.

Comment: What do you mean by JS can do it? You mean for the modification of the form? If yes, I agree but the problem is not the value in the form but how many are render and where. Otherwise could you please explain?

Comment: You can use Javascript to control where you append the form prototype to. No offense, but if you're having difficulties understanding the capabilities of some programming techniques, it might be a better idea to start off with something simpler than Symfony. It can get quite complicated sometimes and you can get lost easily.

Comment: Offense done. I've no difficulties with JS or Symfony in general and I was asking for a Symfony solution, if one existed, not a JS fix.